# Service and Activity

Tags: android, service, binding, android-activity

I have a service GPS.java and an activity message.java which is bound to the mentioned service(GPS.java). I have bounded them using binder and service connection. I want the values of my activity class which i have sent using putExtra(Sring,value). How would i receive them in my service?

Comment: I think you have to provide some example code of what you have

Answer (score 0):

If you supplied the values in the intent when you launched/binded to the service you can access the data from [`Intent.getExtras`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras())

However, if you're using a binder you need to create a method for giving the service values as the intent received in `onBind` will not contain any extras.

Here is an example:

In the service:

```
private final ExampleBinder binder = new ExampleBinder();

private class ExampleBinder extends Binder {
    public void setExtras(Bundle b) {
        // Set extras and process them
    }

    public ExampleService getService() {
        return ExampleService.this;
    }

    public void registerClient(ClientInterface client) {
        synchronized(clients) {
            clients.add(client);
        }
    }

    public void unregisterClient(ClientInterface client) {
        synchronized(clients) {
            clients.remove(client);
        }
    }
};

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}

private final HashSet<ClientInterface> clients = new HashSet<ClientInterface>();

public static interface ClientInterface {
    int value1();
    String value2();
}
```

In the client:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity implements ExampleService.ClientInterface {
    private final ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // Handle unexpected disconnects (crashes)
        }

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            ExampleService.ExampleBinder binder = (ExampleService.ExampleBinder) service;
            binder.registerClient(ExampleActivity.this);
        }
    };

public void onResume() {
    bindService(new Intent(this, ExampleService.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

public void onPause() {
    unbindService(connection);
}

public int value1() {
    return 4711;
}

public String value2() {
    return "foobar";
}
```

I can add that this is all assuming you're not using AIDL, if you are the solution is quite similar, just add an extra method in your interface declaration.

You should read more about bound services here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html
or see an example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

There is also an example included in the SDK called LocationService.java

Comment: I think Intent.getExtras can be used only for onStart()..but i am using bindService().

Comment: You will need to create methods in your binder that allows you to set the data after you've bound to the service.

Comment: i want to read values from my activity in my service? Is there any way we can read these values in the activity using the R.java file directly ? or not please show me the relevant code to do so using binders?